# Email confirmation layout is displayed improperly for gmail.com (used backend is Node.js)

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, inline-styles

I try to create an email confirmation layout for my web project and everything is just fine for **mail.ru** server, but when I try to send a letter to **gmail.com** it goes to spam and is improperly styled (I use flex and inline styling). As for the question concerning going it to spam I already know it's something about domain issue and I should solve it on the server side (both google support and hosting say that), but how it is being displayed, they say it's connected to my program code. According to their advice I made up my mind to post it here in hope to get a solution concerning my improper styling (I send here wrong and correct attachments demostrating the current layouts) which is due to my lack of experience with Node.js. So here is the script:

Node.js-script **nodemailer_express_hbs:**

```js
const path = require('path')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');
 
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
 
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/var/www/www-root/data/www/myadobepics.ru/my-app/myadobepics.ru.key');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/var/www/www-root/data/www/myadobepics.ru/my-app/myadobepics.ru.crtca');
 
const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
 
const app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.myadobepics.ru',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'admin@myadobepics.ru',
        pass: '***'
    }
});
 
const message = {
    from: 'admin@myadobepics.ru',    
    to: '***',  
    subject: 'Registration at https://myadobepics.ru',
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'logo.png',
        path: __dirname + '/pics/logo.png',
        cid: 'logo'
    }],
    template: 'confirm',
    context: {
        nickname: 'yourname',
        email: 'youremail', 
        password: 'yourpassword', 
        gen: 'gencode'
    }
};
 
const options = {
    viewEngine: {
        extName: ".hbs",
        partialsDir: path.resolve('./views'),
        defaultLayout: false,
    },
    viewPath: path.resolve('./views'),
    extName: ".hbs",
};
 
transport.use('compile', hbs(options));
 
transport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("E-mail was sent!");
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
 
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
 
httpsServer.listen(3344, function () {
    console.log("Waiting for user info on port 3344...");
});
```

Next I provide styling which is in the folder called **views** (this folder should be in the same directory as the script itself):

File **confirm.hbs:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Email confirmation for https://myadobepics.ru</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;width: 100%;height: 100vh;background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(204, 232, 250) 0%, rgb(197, 235, 255) 50%) 0% 0% repeat scroll;">
        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: flex-start;align-items: center;width: 30vw;height: 75vh;background-color: #FFF;border-radius: calc(1vw + 1vh);border: 10px solid black;padding: calc(1vw + 1vh);">
            <img src="cid:logo" style="width: 20vw;height: auto;" />
            <hr style="width: 12vw;margin-top: 2vh;color: #8CC9FF;">
            <p style="margin-top: 10vh;width: 25vw;text-align: justify;color: black;font-size: calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);">Hello, <b>{{nickname}}</b>! Thank you for your registration! Please, press a button below if you want to confirm it.</p>
            <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;width: 7vw;height: 1vh;background-color: lightskyblue;border-radius: calc(0.6vw + 0.6vh);border: none;margin: calc(1vw + 1vh);padding: calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);cursor: pointer;">
                <a href="https://myadobepics.ru:1122/verify?email={{email}}&nickname={{nickname}}&gen={{gen}}" style="text-decoration: none;color: white;padding: calc(1vw + 1vh);font-size: calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);">CONFIRM</a>
            </div>
            <p style="margin-top: 1vh;width: 25vw;text-align: justify;color: black;font-size: calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);">To log in you can use the credentials we have provided next.</p>
            <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: flex-start;align-items: flex-start;margin-top: 1vh;width: 25vw;font-size: calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);">
                <div><b>Your login: </b><span>{{email}}</span></div>
                <div><b>Your password: </b><span>{{password}}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: flex-start;align-items: flex-start;margin-top: 10vh;width: 25vw;font-size: calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);">
                <div>Best regards,</div>
                <div>Administrator</div>
                <div>E-mail: admin@myadobepics.ru</div>
            </div>
            <span style="margin-top: 2vh;color: maroon;font-size: calc(0.5vw + 0.5vh);">This link will be expired in 24 hours</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As for the image in the file above you may choose any one as email confirmation logo in case you will be running this code. It should be inside folder called **pics** which you will have to create at the same directory tree level as the script itself (just like the folder called **views**).

Here are two attachments for proper and improper styling:

https://postimg.cc/t1YnSnnZ
https://postimg.cc/Jtc3BJNM

If anyone knows how to solve my issue or knows another solution for this problem using Node.js I would be very glad to hear your replies.

Best regards,
Kirill

Comment: Hi Kirill. I don't have much experience with emails sent, but I remember one time that I need to do it for my business, and someone told me that I should do everything in tables instead of using flex. And every email I sent from my business to costumers, works fine. Don't know if this will be your answer but you can try.

Comment: Hello, Ricardo. Thank you very much for your reply. I tried to use tables and it helped much . It looks just fine both at mail.ru and gmail.com. Now I need to check other mail servers to make sure everything is correct.